# Can we reconstruct a regular variety from its $D$-$\mathrm{mod}$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

The famous [Gabriel-Rosenberg reconstruction theorem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.5978) states that the pre-additive category of quasi-coherent sheaves on a quasi-separated scheme contains enough information to recover the scheme.

One can ask a similar question for $D$-modules. An immediate issue is that $D$-modules do not see nonreducedness. Another problem is that the normalization map may induce [an equivalence](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.712.1862&rep=rep1&type=pdf) on the categories of $D$-modules. The following seems to pass the basic sanity checks: can one recover a regular Noetherian scheme from the pre-additive category of (left) $D$-modules on it?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by a D-module on a singular scheme. One standard definition would be to embed in to a smooth variety, then look at D-modules on the ambient space with support on the subvariety. This is not the same in general as the category of sheaves of modules for the ring of Grothendieck differential operators. In some large generality, the former notion agrees with the category of crystals on the scheme which is generally regarded to be the "correct" notion. Crystals, by definition, do not see nonreducedness, but I am not sure about rings of differential operators.

Comment: Ah, I just saw that you restricted to regular schemes at the end.